# How to use QFileSystemWatcher

Tags: qt, qfilesystemwatcher

I'd like to detect when a SDCARD or USB is inserted in my QT based linux embedded System. I made the following, but I think something is missing:

```
    FSwatcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(this);
    FSwatcher->addPath("/run/media");
    connect(FSwatcher, SIGNAL(directoryChanged(QString)), this,SLOT(showModifiedDirectory(QString)));
}
void ts400::showModifiedDirectory(QString)
{
qDebug() << "Detected++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++";
}
```

I don't understand why the connector doens't function (no call to my Slot).
Is there someone who can give some instruction about?
Thanks

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with you code -- have you verified that the device does indeed show up in /run/media?

Comment: I haven't checked but I suspect `QFileSystemWatcher` on linux makes use of [`inotify`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).  Unfortunately certain parts of the file system (or, perhaps more correctly, their 'drivers') don't support the `inotify` protocol.  That may well be the case for `/run/media` in which case you won't receive any signals.

Comment: You can try a different approach - get a listing of `run/media` directory periodically (e.g. every second) and compare with the previous values if the list changed. This should be fairly simple.